# MATLAB Multiple Input Machine Learning

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision

I currently face a problem of trying to combine multiple heatmaps and produce a result with the most significant region.

For example, I have an image with a dog in it and produced three heatmaps from it, called HeatMap1, HeatMap2, and HeatMap 3. I also have a rectangular box that sets where the dog is as ground truth.

The problem now is that I want the associate different weights to the different heatmaps, so that the "rectangular box" can be maximized. So I expect the results be like x1*HeatMap1 + x2*HeatMap2 + x3*HeatMap3. I wonder what machine learning algorithm would help me. Some guidance would be helpful, since I am new in Machine Learning.

Comment: A little more detail would be helpful. What are the sizes for `x1,x2,x3` and `HeatMap`? `x1*HeatMap1 + x2*HeatMap2 + x3*HeatMap3 = ?`

Comment: Could you provide some pictures or a more specific description on what exact problem you want to solve?
Do you want to detect the dog on a heatmap?
If you want to mark an object on a picture OpenCV has many algorithms for that.

Comment: You need to define your problem better. What is exactly your goal? maximizing an expression without putting any restrictions is not a good goal you need to had some restriction like: "maximazing the values in the rectangle box while minimizing the values outside of the box". or "maximazing the values in the rectangle box while the sum of all the pixels values in all the images is boundued by something and the sum of X1 X2 and X3 sum to 1"  (I think this is why NKN asked to get the sizes of the values .